# Woocommerce Product Ordering Drop-down box disappears for no reason

Tags: php, woocommerce

On my website the product ordering drop-down box disappeared after I changed any option or went to a new page.

After fiddling around I went the the file woocommerce/includes/wc-template-fuctions.php and changed

```
function woocommerce_catalog_ordering() {
    if ( ! wc_get_loop_prop( 'is_paginated' ) || ! woocommerce_products_will_display() ) {
        return;
    }
```

to

```
function woocommerce_catalog_ordering() {
    if ( ! wc_get_loop_prop( 'is_paginated' ) || ! woocommerce_products_will_display() ) {
        echo 'test';
        return;
    }
```

And this has fixed the problem entirely. Now I'm not one to look a gift horse in the mouth, but I would **really** like to know why this has solved the issue because I've tried lots of other things and I can't figure out why this should work.

Notes:

- I have to print actual words
- If I print html the text will appear and replace the dropdown box
- removing the return breaks this fix